# What's that yellow gauge above my life bar?

Tags: dead-cells

Since I've reached the High peak castle level, this gauge has appeared:

[image: Yellow gauge]

After the level, when I replenished my life and potion in the Passage to the throne room, the gauge vanished.

Any idea what it is ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The yellow bar is actually a "Malaise" gauge:

> Aside from damage, you get a stack of malaise every time you get hit by one of the three elites that hold keys in Castle. If the bar of malaise reach maximum - you die. So don't get hit by those elites ([source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/588650/discussions/0/1696048879949789619/))

Also:

> **Infection**
>
> - Taking damage from Key Elite in The Castle causes infection.
> - Maximum tier of infection is 10.
>
>   - Key Elites' hits gives you 2 points of infection.
>   - After reaching maximum infection tier, you start taking enormous damage, then you just die.
> - This effect can occur from Prisoners' Cells if 4 Boss Source Cells are inoculated (currently exclusive to the Baguette Update alpha.).
>
>   - In that case, every enemy can foment infection.
>
> ([source](https://deadcells.gamepedia.com/Mechanics#Infection))